# Download Firebase files from Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase-storage

I have some files in the assets folder in order to use them offline.

Now, I need to download files from firebase, but need to check if these files exist or not.

Need sample code and Thanks in advance.

Please Help with sample code.

Comment: A quick search turns up this: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/11620. You might want to give the code in that issue report a try to see if it works for you. If not, report back with what you tried and what result (and error, if any) you got.

Answer (score 2):

You have said that you need to check whether the files exist or not. Just trying to download the images to local file on the device and doing error handling should work well.

Code -

```dart
final islandRef = storageRef.child("images/island.jpg");

final appDocDir = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
final filePath = "${appDocDir.absolute}/images/island.jpg";
final file = File(filePath);

final downloadTask = islandRef.writeToFile(file);
downloadTask.snapshotEvents.listen((taskSnapshot) {
  switch (taskSnapshot.state) {
    case TaskState.running:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      break;
    case TaskState.paused:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      break;
    case TaskState.success:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      break;
    case TaskState.canceled:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      break;
    case TaskState.error:
      // TODO: Handle this case.
      break;
  }
});
```

the last case should be the one that will tell you whether the file is there.